# Kernel panic on "apt-get upgrade" with DWA-160

Tags: networking, apt, kernel-panic

I'm running on a minimal Ubuntu server 12.04.3 install and I installed a d-link DWA-160 usb wifi adapter as per the instructions shown in [this page](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/229-ubuntu-precise-dlink-dwa160-revb2).

After successfully connecting using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line) (I basically ping google to confirm that I'm connected), I try to run apt-get update but end up getting what appears to be a kernel panic every time I do.

The connection does not seem stable during the update process. For instance, as I'm typing this I've tried again and it seems stuck at :

```
9% [4 Release 3,980B/49.6 kB 8%]
[Waiting for headers]
[Waiting for headers]
```

I usually get a kernel panic shortly thereafter.

I'll try to provide info as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the symptoms (crashes when there's a lot of network traffic, and you happen to be using a custom network driver), it's a bug in the network driver.

From the page you link:

> DWA 160 is also know to freeze under heavy network load. When this happens, the only solution is to unplug and replug the key. Till date this bug has not been corrected.
>
> Because of all that, this wifi key is not, at this time, a very good deal for Linux users.

Report a bug to the providers of the driver. This isn't something that can be worked around, other than not using the driver or using a fixed version of the driver.

Comment: I don't know though. At first blush, it doesn't seem like heavy network load. But if it were, is there no way to control it by putting a cap on it?
In any case, I didn't expect very reliable performance from this adapter.

Comment: @TheCoconutChef You can put a bandwidth limit and hope it helps, but there's no guarantee that heavy load is the problem. It could be a packet with a particular content, a connection in a particular state, …